# problem with running a java web application on command prompt

Tags: java

i have a simple project where there is a html file as view, a servlet as controller and few java files as models. The java files contain some information that need to be printed on console. I have been able to compile the classes successfully.How do i run it from command prompt so that the output appears on console

Comment: If you run it with tomcat you can see the console output in the log files.

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you want as the end result. Do you want to control the application from the command line or do you want to start the application and view it from a browser?

Comment: What do you use to compile/build your project? Maven? Ant? Other?

Comment: Also, are you already producing a WAR file?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a web.xml file and archive all the files into a .war file.  Then you can deploy that .war file to Tomcat.  Tomcat will write all your System.out.println() stuff to catalina.out.

Alternatively, you can create a new Java class with a main() method that calls the parts of your code that write to the console.  You can then run that class as you would normally run a Java application in the console.

Comment: thanks. And one more thing while compiling the classes the servlets and java files are in different packages.The servlet references a java file how do i go about compiling these.Is there any particular order?

Comment: As long as you pass all your .java files to the java compiler (javac) at the same time, the order won't matter.  e.g. javac my_application/com/package1/MyClass1.java my_application/com/package2/MyClass2.java

Answer (score 0):

If you are already building a WAR file (Web Application Archive) and you are using [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) for a build tool, you can use the [maven-jetty-plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin). It is very easy to configure. It will allow you to run a command from a command prompt (or shell) like:

```
mvn jetty:run
```

It will run your webapp from a console and print all logs messages to that console. You kill the process with the standard `Ctrl+C` shortcut.

If you are not using Maven, you can still use [Jetty](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Jetty+Wiki) as a web server, it just takes a bit more work. It is very lightweight either way though but this wouldn't be much different than using tomcat or any other servlet containers.